# GIT clone all repositories in parallel i.e. total time taken to clone all is close to what you'd take for the largest repo: fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git, github, ssh, parallel-processing, git-clone

OK. Mac OS.

```
alias gcurl
alias gcurl='curl -s -H "Authorization: token IcIcv21a5b20681e7eb8fe7a86ced5f9dbhahaLOL" '

echo $IG_API_URL 
https://someinstance-git.mycompany.com/api/v3
```

Ran the following to see: list of all orgs that a user has access to. 
**NOTE:** *to a new user (passing just $IG_API_URL here will give you all the REST end points that one can use)*.

```
gcurl ${IG_API/URL}/user/orgs
```

Running the above gave me a nice JSON object output which I plunged into `jq`and got the info and finally now I have the corresponding git url that I can use to clone a repo.

I created a master repo file:

```
git@someinstance-git.mycompany.com:someorg1:some-repo1.git
git@someinstance-git.mycompany.com:someorg1:some-repo2.git
git@someinstance-git.mycompany.com:someorg2:some-repo1.git
git@someinstance-git.mycompany.com:someorgN:some-repoM.git
...
....
some 1000+ such entries here in this file.
```

I created a small oneliner script (read the lines one by one - I know it's sequential but) and ran git clone , which works fine.

What I hate and trying to find a better solution is:
1) It's doing it sequentially and it's slow (i.e. one by one thing).

2) I want to clone all repos **under the max time it will take the largest repo to clone**. i.e. if repo A takes 3 seconds, B takes 20 and C takes 3 and all other repos take under 10 seconds, then I'm wondering if there's a way to clone all repos quickly under **20**-30 seconds (versus 3+20+3+...+...+... seconds>minutes which would be a lot).

To do the same, I tried my mind's poverty ran the git clone step in background so that I can iterate faster enough to read those lines.

```
git clone ${git_url_line} $$_${datetimestamp}_${git_repo_fetch_from_url} &
```

Hey, the script ended quickly and running `ps -eAf|egrep "ssh|git"` showed something fun was running. Coincidently one of the guy shouted :) that Incinga is showing cool metrics for something very high. I thought it was due to me, but I guess I could do N no. of git clones from my GIT instances without impacting any network outage / something weird.

OK, things ran successfully for sometime and I started seeing bunch of git clone output on my screen. On the second session, I saw folders were getting populated just fine, until I finally saw what I was expecting not to:

```
Resolving deltas: 100% (3392/3392), done.
remote: Total 5050 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 5050
Receiving objects: 100% (5050/5050), 108.50 MiB | 1.60 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1777/1777), done.
remote: Total 10691 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 10691
Receiving objects: 100% (10691/10691), 180.86 MiB | 1.57 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5148/5148), done.
remote: Total 5994 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 5968
Receiving objects: 100% (5994/5994), 637.66 MiB | 2.61 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3017/3017), done.
Checking out files: 100% (794/794), done.
packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.20.30.40 port 22: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, what is the desired behaviour and output?  Do you maybe want to bound the number of processes cloning (I suspect 1k processes is going to perform rather poorly both for the git server and the local machine) -- perhaps you want something like `xargs -P10 --replace git clone {} < repos.txt`

Comment: @AnthonySottile I see. I'll try that and agree that it'd be a better solution when it comes to performance and resource bandwidth / impact. Thanks Anthony.

Comment: @AnthonySottile not sure `--replace` or `-replace` is a valid option for xargs though. Giving me this error: `xargs: illegal option -- -` or `error: unknown switch `P'` or `Too many arguments`

Comment: Ah, I'm using GNU xargs, I suspect you're using BSD xargs (osx?)? -- In that case you probably want `xargs -I{} -P10 git clone {}`

Comment: Hey guess what, that's what I was looking for (at least). You can post, I'll accept it as an answer. Thanks Anthony.

Comment: I'll rewrite as an answer with a little more prose :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're exhausting resources either on your local machine or on the remote machine by starting ~1000 processes at once.  You probably want to limit the number of processes started.  One technique for that is to use `xargs`.

If you have access to GNU xargs, it might look something like this:

```
xargs --replace -P10 git clone {} < repos.txt
```

- `-P10` is "10 processes"
- `--replace` - replace the `{}` with the mapped argument

If you're stuck with crippled BSD `xargs` such as on osx (or want higher compatibility) you can use the more portable:

```
xargs -I{} -P10 git clone {} < repos.txt
```

This form will also work with GNU xargs as well

Comment: I like the word, crippled. Thanks.

Comment: ok, I did some perf testing using various number with `-P<N>` and it seems like the lower the number close to 10, the better (i.e. if it's closer to the no. of CPU core) the higher the chance that a user will not see any fatal / connection errors. Sometimes, the run worked for -P10 to -P100 even -P500 but the success rate of -P10 was always successful without reflecting any network/resource related errors for running parallel processes.

Comment: The only thing bumping me atm is if my master repo file, contained rows in it from various instances, their individual orgs, org's repositories where repository name in one GIT instance/org is similar to other org within the same instance OR same in a different GIT instance in any org, then this solution currently just gives that repo folder already exist, so it'll not git clone that next repository if the named folder already exist (GIT expected behavior). I'll see how I can achieve `git clone <git_url> <some_git_instance_org_repo_folder>` using the xargs way. Will post the solution.

Comment: Can probably do instead `xargs -I{} -P10 bash -c 'git clone {} $(cut -d: -f2 {})' < repos.txt`, this'll allow you to do some bash string parsing of the repo name to control where the repository ends up

Comment: Cool, that's the hint I was looking for. Thanks Anthony. I'll play with Bash, cut/var substitution and get it working. If the cloned folder can be named as "<git_instance>_<git_org>_<git_repo>", solution achieved.

Comment: `xargs -I{} -P10 bash -c 'git clone {} $(echo {} | cut -d'@' -f2 | sed "s#\:#__#g;s#/#__#g;s#\.git##")' < repos.txt` -- all good now. Note: I had to use `echo {}` within `$(... ...... | cut ...)` otherwise it didn't work.

Comment: sweeet!  ah yeah ++ on the echo bit (typed it in a hurry and didn't bother trying it heh) -- with newer versions of bash you can pipe a string to stdin with `<<<` (so you could do `cut -d@ -f2 <<< {} | sed ...`)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anthony.

To perform GIT clone in parallel (up to a given -P for xargs), I tried various numbers (`-P5`, `-P10`, `-P15`,... , `-P100`,...`-P<Limit_number_as_per_ulimit>`, `-P<No.of.processes_a_user_can_have_at_a_given_time>`). Conclusion was to stick to either **xargs** `-P5` or `-P10` as higher number was for `-P<N>`, it was not successful every time (due to resource issues () at the machine on which I ran the command/script).

If you increase the -P (N value), you may see errors like:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.20.30.40 port 22: Broken pipe
or
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
or
fatal: early EOF
or
fatal: index-pack failed
or
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
or
ssh: connect to host somegit-instance.mycompany.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

**Final script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
pattern=""; # Create git pattern to fetch enteries from master config based upon user's parameters, defaults to blank.

usage() {
 echo -e "\nUsage:\n------\ngit-clone-repos.parallel.sh [usage | help | <pattern>]\n"
 echo "git-clone-repos.parallel.sh \"github.mycompany.com\"             .................................... (This will re-clone every repository under every org in Git instance 'github.mycompany.com')"
 echo "git-clone-repos.parallel.sh \"github.mycompany.com:tools-ansible-some-org\"  ................ (This will re-clone every repository under org: 'tools-ansible-some-org' in Git instance 'github.mycompany.com')"
 echo "git-clone-repos.parallel.sh \"somegit-instance.mycompany.com:coolrepo-org/somerepo.git\"  .... (This will re-clone repo: 'somerepo' in org: 'coolrepo-org' in Git instance: 'somegit-instance.mycompany.com')"
 echo -e "\n\n"
}

# If help/usage as first arg, show usage help
if [[ ("$1" == "usage" || "$1" == "help") || $# -eq 0 ]]; then usage; exit 0; fi

# Set pattern
pattern="$1"
mc_file=~/AKS/common/master-config.git-repos-ssh-urls.txt
echo "-- Master config file: $mc_file"; echo
echo "-- Pattern passed for fetching repos from master config file is: \"$pattern\""

# Create a workspace dir in PWD so that everything sits fresh in a new folder. Tweak it if you don't want it.
dir="$$_$(date +%s)"
mkdir ${dir} && cd $dir

# First create a temp repo file filtered by pattern and for '@' lines only (i.e. ignoring commented out lines)
tmprepofile=$(mktemp)
grep "${pattern}" ${mc_file} | grep '@' | cut -d':' -f3- > ${tmprepofile}

# GIT clone in parallel mode (xargs -P5 is optimal, -P10 can be used).
# Git a repo as a different name so that all repos in any organization in any instance clones without any conflict.
xargs -I{} -P10 bash -c 'git clone {} $(echo {} | cut -d'@' -f2 | sed "s#\:#__#g;s#/#__#g;s#\.git##")' < ${tmprepofile}
```

**Sample master config file used was:**

```
#-- Sample Master Config file, which can be generated using GIT rest api - against a user's org to find all user org repositories (in my case) looks like:
## github coolrepo-org org/repogroup contains:
##-----------
github.mycompany.com:coolrepo-org:git@github.mycompany.com:coolrepo-org/somerepo1.git
github.mycompany.com:coolrepo-org:git@github.mycompany.com:coolrepo-org/somerepo2.git

## somegit-instance pipeline org/repogroup contains:
##-----------
somegit-instance.mycompany.com:pipeline:git@somegit-instance.mycompany.com:pipeline/shinynew-cool-pipeline.git

## !!!!! NO ORG ACCESS REPO ENTRIES BELOW !!!!! ##
## -----------------------------------------------
## somegit-instance Misc no access org but access at just repo level enteries contains:
##----------- (appended to the master file at the end of master file generation script) ---------
somegit-instance.mycompany.com:someorg-org:git@somegit-instance.mycompany.com:someorg-org/somerepofooter.git
somegit-instance.mycompany.com:someorg-org:git@somegit-instance.mycompany.com:someorg-org/somereponav.git
```